# Get hash values (from a number of hashes) in an array and sum them up

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I currently have an array of hashes:

```
total_order = [{"Hamburger"=>5.0}, {"Hamburger"=>5.0}, {"Hamburger"=>5.0}]
```

I'm trying to iterate over each hash in this array and then sum all of the values. So essentially I want to return 15.0.

Here is my code at the moment. I'm not even trying to sum it yet, just return each value so that I can sum it after. When I run it I only get the array returned:

```
  def total_order_cost
    total_order.each do |item|
      item.map do |k, v|
        print v
      end
    end
  end
```

Any idea how I go about iterating over the hashes and then sum the values within? Have checked other people's questions but don't seem to be able to make any of the solutions work in my case. Other answers I have seen do not address my question and do not include solutions such as the use of flat_map.

Comment: @Andrey, yes, a dup, but it's curious that the selected answer here would have been incorrect when the referenced question was asked many moons ago. I have two minds about the rule that dups are out-of-bounds. On the one hand it reduces clutter and may expose good answers to the earlier posting, but more than one I've seen an answer to a dup that was much better than any of the earlier answers. One could of course post another answer to the original question, but few may see it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland while I agree that sometimes (really rarely) referenced questions can not contain as good answer as provided to a dup, in this particular case there is no need to repeat the answer because it is as simple as "get hash values and sum them up", which basically *every* answer in this thread and referenced thread does. P.S. The prob with the accepted answer in referenced question is that OP wanted to get a hash as result, but still answers show how to "get hash values and sum them up"

Comment: @AndreyDeineko, OP here. I actually did want to "get hash values and sum them up" and not get a hash as a result. This was answered really well here. I have reworded to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sum the values of a hash:

```
{a:1,b:2}.values.sum
#=> 3
```

And to do that for your array of hashes:

```
total_order.flat_map(&:values).sum
#=> 15.0
```

Note that `sum` is only available in Ruby 2.4.0 and later (and in Rails). In older versions you can use `reduce(:+)` and `inject(:+)` instead of `sum`.

Comment: Perfect. This worked. What does the flat_map(&:values) part actually do?

Comment: Same as `.map(&:values).flatten` i.e. get the values in the hashes and turn them into a single array. (See Jörg's answer.)

Answer (score 3):

This is the most succinct way I came up with:

```
2.1.2 :013 > [{a:1},{b:2}].map(&:values).flatten.inject(:+)
=> 3
```

`values` returns just the values, not the keys, as an array and then `inject` sums them all together.  [`inject` is a great function](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject), and really helped me think in terms of list comprehensions, which this kinda is.

Comment: Thanks for this. When I do 

```x.values```

I get ```[[5.0], [5.0], [5.0]]```

When I do ```x.values.inject(0){|sum,x|sum+x}``` I get ```[5.0, 5.0, 5.0]```

Any idea how I sum it all together at the end?

Comment: I'll update my answer.

Comment: tuple_cat's answer is even a little better.

Answer (score 1):

Your method returns the result of `total_oder.each`, and [`Array#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-each) just returns `self`, so your method simply returns `total_order`. This is true for all implementations of `each`, by the way, not just for `Array`; it is the standard protocol for `each`. `each` is intended to be used only for the block's side-effects.

If you want to *transform* an [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html), you need to use [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), which transforms each element using the given block.

So, you want to get all the values from the [`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html)es. Look at [the documentation of `Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html) and see if you can spot a method that could possibly be used to return the values. What about [`Hash#values`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-values), that sounds good, doesn't it?

```
total_order.map(&:values)
#=> [[5.0], [5.0], [5.0]]
```

Now, we want to get rid of that extra level of nesting, we could use [`Array#flatten`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-flatten) for that, but it is much better to make sure that the nesting doesn't occur in the first place, so we use [`Enumerable#flat_map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) instead of `Enumerable#map`:

```
total_order.flat_map(&:values)
#=> [5.0, 5.0, 5.0]
```

Okay, next you want to sum those values. Again, let's just look at [the documentation of `Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html). What could a method that sums the items of an `Enumerable` possibly be called. How does [`Enumerable#sum`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) sound?

```
total_order.flat_map(&:values).sum
#=> 15.0
```

And there you have your desired result. The moral of the story is: learn the methods in `Enumerable`, they are the bread and butter of Ruby programming. And, learn to navigate [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/).

Answer (score 0):

```
sum = 0
def total_order_cost
  total_order.each do |item|
    item.each do |k,v|
        sum = sum + v
     end
   p sum
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not too far off:

```
total_order = [{"Hamburger"=>5.0}, {"Hamburger"=>5.0}, {"Hamburger"=>5.0}]

def total_order_cost(order)
  cost = 0
  order.each do |item|
    item.each do |k, v|
      cost = cost + v
    end
  end
  return cost
end

puts total_order_cost(total_order) # 15.0
```